# How to properly split a site?

Tags: web, sitemap, robots.txt, google-search-console

Suppose I have a **new** verison of a website:

```
 http://www.mywebsite.com
```

and I have would like to keep the **older** site in a sub-directory and treat it seperately:

```
 http://www.mywebsite.com/old/
```

My **new** site has a link to the **old** one on the main page, but not vice-versa.

1) Should I create 2 sitemaps? One for the **new** and one for the **old**?

2) When my site gets crawled, how can I limit the path of the crawler? In other words, since the **new** site has a link to the **old** one, the crawler will reach the **old** site. If I do the following in my robots.txt:

```
 User-agent: *
 Disallow: /old/
```

I'm worried that it won't crawl the **old** site (using the 2nd sitemap) since it's blocked. Is that correct?

Comment: Any ideas?  I'm still boggled by this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You could include all URLs in one file, or you could create separate files. One could understand a sitemap as "per (web) site", e.g. see http://www.sitemaps.org/:

> In its simplest form, a Sitemap is an XML file that lists URLs **for a site** along with additional metadata about each URL

Since you now have two sites, you may create two sitemaps. But again, I don't think that it is strictly defined that way.

2) Well, if you block the URLs in robots.txt, these URLs won't be visited by conforming bots. It doesn't mean that these *URLs* will never be indexed by search engines, but the pages (= the content) will not.